# Receiving a json response in Symfony 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, symfony

I have a javascript event listener on the `search.html.twig` page that will trigger an ajax request. In the example below, my goal is for the ajax call to be successful so the `alert()` message is executed.

I am used to the flat PHP approach:

`echo json_encode($myAry);`

Symfony's routing system makes returning an json response to ajax confusing. I am currently getting an internal server error 500.

I appreciate any advice on how to troubeshoot this. Thank in advance!

DefaultController

```
     public function showCompanyAction($id)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Company');
        //get company based on id

        //prepare json object

        //return it to search.html.twig
        return new JsonResponse(array('name' => 'hello'));  
    }
```

JQuery (search.html.twig)

```
{% block jquery %} 
    <script>
        $(function(){


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../company/booth/2",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: sf 2.1? With JsonResponse() should be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a json response in Symfony2, you have to return this from the controller called by the route defined for `company/booth/2`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class YourController
{
    public function YourAction()
    {
        $response = json_encode(array('message' => 'hello'));

        return new Response($response, 200, array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ));
    }
}
```

The `200` in the response is the [Http Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html). 200 means "the request was fulfilled".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, this did not work. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I forgot the json_encode() part. Try this new version, it should work with this simple array. However, you will have to serialize your entity to deliver Json content about your Doctrine's Entity.

Comment: +1, it worked! Thank you! It turns out it was a problem with the routing. I had to remove the `2` from the path... and adjust the `routing.yml`/ controller accordingly. Question, what is the `200` for in the response?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend nice ;) - did you manage to deliver what you wanted in the end?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend 200 is http status code for "request fulfilled". Basically, it tells the browser that everything went ok in the delivery. 500 for instance (what you had previously) would be Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 4):

Jivan's answer is good, here is a more maintainable alternative:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class YourController
{
    public function yourAction()
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array('message' => 'hello'));

        return $response;
    }
}
```

With this solution, you don't need to encode the array and specify the response headers (`Content-Type` and all). If the specificity of JSON responses change then you won't have to worry about updating your code.

Comment: Exactly.  This is very clear and concise, and i think this is consistent with the s2 documentation.  This allows for easy manipuation of `$response` data before returning, makes it very clear whats being returned, and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

To process a JsonResponse with jQuery, you can do it with the "each" function:

```
public function showCompanyAction($id)
{
    return new JsonResponse(
        array(
            array('name' => 'hello'),
            array('name' => 'bye'),
        )
    );  
}

{% block jquery %} 
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../company/booth/2",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    alert(element.name);
                });
            }
        })
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```